# how can i access the table not created by @entity?

Tags: playframework

I know that i can use @entity to create a table in playframework. But now I have a table in the same database but was created by James. I want to access the table in my webapp with playframework. how can i do that?  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use JDBC for database access if you want, like:

```
try {
    Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM my_table");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        // do something with the row
    }
    ps.close();
    conn.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```